# How to echo inside html tags

Tags: php

```
Embedding php inside html </p>
<?php
$text ='Click here';
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
?>
 <a href="$link"><php? echo $text; ?></a>
```

Why is this not printing out link and text assigned in the php code inside the html tags?

Comment: Fix the typos and add the PHP tags for executing PHP code.

Comment: Why are all the answers voted down?

Comment: The same question!!! For the question it is ok. But why the answers?

Answer (score 5):

If you'll always be running your code in PHP 5.4+, you could use short echo tags;

```
<?php
$text ='Click here';
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
?>
 <a href="<?= $link ?>"><?= $text ?></a>
```

Looks a little neater in my opinion, but it's a matter of preference, and short echo tags aren't on by default in earlier versions of PHP, so I wouldn't recommend it if your code is ever going to run on server with PHP versions below 5.4

Comment: Your `$link` still won't get echoed. Additionally, in some PHP versions, short tags will generate warnings.

Comment: @Raptor well-spotted. My fault for copy/pasting OP's code without double-checking it. Corrected. I'm not sure in what situations short echo tags would generate warnings if you're using PHP 5.4 or above, though.

Comment: short open tags are once suggested to deprecate in PHP6, thus deprecation notice once appears ... well, the result ends up totally different. Since PHP 5.4 (as well as PHP7), short open tags are always enabled.

Comment: @Raptor: Oh, that's a shame. One more reason to push me towards using a template engine like Twig.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
Embedding php inside html </p>
<?php
$text ='Click here';
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$text.'</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprint`

```
<?php
$text ='Click here';
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
echo sprintf(" <a href="%s">%s</a>", $link, $text);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Embedding php inside html </p>
<?php
$text ='Click here';
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
?>
 <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></a>
```

It is `<?php` not `<php?`

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></a>
```

For the server to interpret your php you need to close all your php code inside the `<?php ?>` tags and then echo that variable

Answer (score 0):

Open PHP tags properly

You can embedd PHP inside  tag as like :

```
<a href="<?php echo $link?>"><?php echo $text;?></a>
```